# UI Update from secondary thread - Performselectoron mainthread or dispatch_get_main_queue

Tags: multithreading, macos, user-interface

I am using (simplified):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                    [progressLevel2 setDoubleValue:songCount];
                });
```

Id like to not redo everything using performselectoronmainthread only to find I have some other issue. Shouldn't my code be working?

Comment: Perhaps if you told us what wasn't working we could help?

Comment: I am updating a progress bar and some other text labels as songs are parsed on a different queue. In some cases, customers are reporting the UI stops updating until they click something, and in some cases they say the UI isnt updating at all and suddenly "jumps" to completed.